# Quick Steps in Outlook quick access toolbar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can the quick steps in Outlook (2013) be added to the quick access toolbar? 
The Microsoft forums have an [(un)helpful answer.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/how-do-i-add-an-individual-quick-step-to-the-quick/db861bd0-6936-4efd-90e6-18bcd62e7ea4)

Quick steps exist on the Home tab of the ribbon in a box, but I have this hidden by default in outlook. I was wondering if a macro could either do this or provide similar functionality, as macros can be added. However I am not familiar with Outlook macros and don't want to lose the mail.

I want to move messages to archive folders (the "done" quick step) so have several quick steps set-up for each.

This unanswered question is similar: [Quick Steps in Outlook 2013 added to all Ribbons](https://superuser.com/questions/790065/quick-steps-in-outlook-2013-added-to-all-ribbons)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you don't want to accept Microsoft's correct answer. You cannot do it because Outlook does not expose an interface to the individual quick steps other than the menu. You *can* add the menu to the quick access toolbar but not individual steps.

Most if not all of the things you can do in quick steps can be done via VBA macros. That certainly includes moving files to a folder. However, as you've intimated, this is not especially simple.

Thankfully, you may find some help in the macro I recently published on Github to do something similar. My macro allows you to select the folder to move to but you should be able to dig out the salient part for your needs. Just practice on some dummy emails first.

The script is called [outlook-filer](https://github.com/TotallyInformation/outlook-filer). There are plenty of other examples of filer scripts on the Internet.

Comment: While the answer on the MS forums is correct, a blunt "no" is not _helpful_. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at the script.

Comment: No worries, sorry if I was a tad blunt as well. We do sometimes get some folk who feel they are entitled to the answer they want :) Feel free to raise an issue in that repo if you need further specifics.